# M2: Category Flat Data re-indexing never finishes?

Tags: magento-2.1, indexing, flat-catalog

So I know this used to be a common problem in M1.x. However, I only recently noticed this in our M2.1.3 environment.

[image: Notice the Processing date]

How can I flush/wipe the Category flat data index and rebuild from scratch?

Comment: If its not production then try to truncate (take a backup before doing so) the category flat table and start the indexing again.

Comment: This is happening in a production environment. However, I can put it in maintenance mode on a slow moment, and do it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It normally happens when the memory limit is few, so increase on your
>   **.htaccess** or **NGINX config**.

Run this command on your MySQL:

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

On you terminal run:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
mage indexer:reindex
```

Comment: my php is set to 2GB of memory usage.

Comment: @Spyrule check your cron too

Answer (score 0):

You can also check mview_state table and set status to idle on that indexer then run it from cli with

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_flat
```

If it break you should see some stack trace in the console

Comment: So interestingly enough, they are all idle, however they are all, also set to disable for mode. Which is odd.